# A sort of converse of Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, pointwise-convergence

$(X, \|•\|) $ and $(Y, \|•\|') $ be two normed space.

$\begin{align} {\scr{B}}{(X, Y) }&=\{T\in {\scr{L}}{(X,Y)}: T \text{ is bounded } \}\end{align}$

$\|T\|_{op}=\sup\{\|Tx\|':\|x\|\le 1 \}$

Question: $\forall (T_n) \subset {\scr{B}}{(X, Y)}$ be such that $T_n\to T $ pointwise $[$ i.e $\forall x\in x,$$ T_nx\to Tx $ in the space  $(Y, \|•\|') ]$ implies $T\in {\scr{B}}{(X, Y)}$.

Does this implies $(X, \|•\|) $ is a Banach space?

The converse is well known ( Banach- Steinhaus theorem) . But i think the above question can be answered negatively , I mean there is some counter examples but neither I can prove it not cite a counter example.

I sincerely need help. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, the answer depends on $Y$. If $Y=\{0\}$ then the hypothesis holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The Banach-Steinhauss Theorem is a consequence of the uniform boundedness principle which in turn holds whenever $X$ is a Baire space.  Non-complete normed spaces which are Baire are therefore counter-examples to your question.

Comment: What is a simple example for a non-complete normed space which is Baire?

Comment: Examples are provided here http://users.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/Baire_incompleto.pdf